# invalid syntax, how to fix?

Tags: python, syntax

Just making a program for school, and I keep getting an invalid syntax on the "set intRnumber" parts. Could someone please help?

```
StrName = ""
StrLevel = ""
intRnumber = 0

StrName = input("What's your name? ")
print("Hello,", StrName)



StrLevel = input("Would you like a low, medium, or high random number? ")
if StrLevel == "low":
    set intRnumber == "5"
elif StrLevel == "medium":
    set intRnumber == "50"
elif StrLevel == "high":
    set intRnumber == "500"
else:
    print("Invalid input, please input low, medium, or high!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you do not perform [assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) the way that you seem to be trying to do it.

You need to do:

```
variable = value
```

Rather than

```
set variable == value
```

You have it right in the first few lines of your code, but the last part of your code would need to be changed to:

```
StrLevel = input("Would you like a low, medium, or high random number? ")
if StrLevel == "low":
    intRnumber = "5"
elif StrLevel == "medium":
    intRnumber = "50"
elif StrLevel == "high":
    intRnumber = "500"
else:
    print("Invalid input, please input low, medium, or high!")
```